# Log4J vulnerability | CVE 2021-44228 in Spring Boot Fix-Bugs in Log4j 2.15.0

Tags: java, spring-boot

How to fix Log4J vulnerability | CVE 2021-44228 in Spring Boot ? Is there any bug in Log4j 2.15.0 version?

Comment: Yes 2.15.0 is still an issue, need to push to 2.16.0

Answer (score -1):

To fix this vulnerability we need to upgrade 2.x version of log4j to at least 2.16.0 or later.

Steps:

1. Go to pom.xml of spring boot project
2. Go to `<properties></properties>` section
3. Add `<log4j2.version>2.16.0</log4j2.version>`

Comment: Which only applies if you are actually using Log4j2, when using the default, logback you don't need to do anything (although upgrading to logback 1.2.8 to prevent a very unlikely case of the same hack might be wise). So blindly upgrading without investigating if one actuallyl uses isn't the way. Which is explained in details here https://spring.io/blog/2021/12/10/log4j2-vulnerability-and-spring-boot

Comment: It's recommend to use <log4j2.version>2.16.0</log4j2.version>

Comment: Which only applies **when you are using log4j2** if you aren't you aren't vulnerable. Spring Boot doesn't use log4j2.